# How to set focus on MS Access form field by using a variable?

Tags: forms, variables, ms-access, setfocus

Looking for a way in a MS Access form to remember the field having the focus, switching the focus by code to other fields (requesting entries from the user) and at the end return to the fiels originally having the focus. I tried following code but everything I try to restore focus generates errors:

```
Dim ctl As Control, prp As Property, hot As String, hit As Object
Set ctl = Screen.ActiveControl
hot = ctl.Name
…
hit = "Forms!" & hot
hit.SetFocus
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Me(hot).SetFocus
```

or

```
Dim hit As Control
Set hit = Me(hot)
hit.SetFocus
```

or simply keeping `ctl` for this:

```
ctl.SetFocus
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Both ways run perfectly:
    ctl.SetFocus
    hot = ctl.Name
    frm(hot).SetFocus